# Error undefined local variable or method `created_at'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I write query to find out how much the user has reduced calories in a week, but I have this error.

How to avoid mistakes?

```
def self.calories_burned(current_user)
  week = ((created_at - current_user.first_program_started_at.utc.beginning_of_day) / 86400 / 7).ceil.to_i || 1
  find_by_sql("
    SELECT 
      count(*) as cnt, 
      WEEK(#{week}) as week_number
    FROM 
      user_daily_updates 
    WHERE 
      user_id=#{current_user.id} 
    GROUP BY 
      week_number
  ")
end
```

Comment: created_at is attached to an insatnce, you're in a class method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### When you write this:

```
def self.calories_burned(current_user)
    etc...
end
```

it's a method that can only be called like this:

`MyUserModel.calories_burned(some_user)`

In this case you are running the code on the class before it is instantiated, this means that the model hasn't even attached itself to a connection to the database and because of that you will not be able to access attributes that pertain to your model.

### On the other hand, if you write this:

```
def calories_burned
    etc...
end
```

You don't need to pass the user to the method, you simply call it on the controller after instantiating your model, like this:

```
id = 123
current_user = MyUserModel.find(id)
current_user.calories_burned
```

where **current_user.calories_burned** will return the value you are looking for based on the current user.

### After taking a closer look at your method

it should look more like this:

```
def calories_burned
    week = ((created_at - first_program_started_at.utc.beginning_of_day) / 86400 / 7).ceil.to_i || 1
    UserDailyUpdate.where(["user_id = ?", id]).where(["week = ?",week]]).count(:all, :group => 'week_number')
end
```

If I understood correctly what you were trying to do with your query, this should give you the same result. Now, I should mention I am assuming that when you created the table **user_daily_updates**, you also created a model UserDailyUpdate.

You should take a look at [ActiveRecord's documentation for searching using conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions) (**all of section 2**) in order to have a better understanding of what I just did.

Answer (score 1):

Apneadiving is right, but I would also look to refactor your code:

```
def self.calories_burned(current_user)
   week = ((##created_at## - current_user.first_program_started_at.utc.beginning_of_day) / 86400 / 7).ceil.to_i || 1
   select("#{self.table_name}.*, count(*) as cnt, WEEK(#{week}) as week_number").where(user_id: current_user.id).group(:week_number)
end
```

You'll need to pull `created_at` from the db, as it won't be present unless you have an instance of a class already loaded

Comment: Thanks for refactoring.

Comment: No problem - hope it helped!